# Characteristic function of convolution?

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

Professor in class stated this:

Let $G(x)$ be the distribution function of a Laplace(0,1) R.V., and $\Psi(t)$ its characteristic function. For each $\epsilon >0$, Define $G_\epsilon=G(\frac{x}{\epsilon}).$ Set $H_\epsilon=F* G_\epsilon$, where F is a general distribution function then

$\lambda_\epsilon(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx}dH_\epsilon(x)=\varphi(t)\Psi(\epsilon t)$, where $\varphi(t)$ is the characteristic function of F .

I have tried to prove this too little avail, can someone guide me please. This was part of the proof for the inversion formula for characteristic functions.

Comment: This should be easy, so you are probably overthinking some detail. What's your definition of "characteristic function"?

Comment: I know t as $E[e^{itx}]$

Comment: Good.  Where do you get stuck?  At the $\Psi(ct)$ step or the $\phi(t)\Psi(ct)$ step?

Comment: Handling the $\Psi(\epsilon t)$ step is maybe easier.  What is $G_\epsilon$ the distribution function of?

Comment: This is what I have so far. $\int_{R}e^{itx}dH_\epsilon(x)=\int_{R}e^{itx}\int_{R}F(w)G(x-w)dwdx=\int_{R}\int_{R}F(w)G(x-w)dxdw$ Let s=x-w then, $\int_{R}F(w)\int_{R}e^{it(w+s)}G(s)dsdw=\int_{R}e^{itw}F(w)\int_{R}e^{its}G(s)dsdw=\int_{R}e^{itw}F(w)\Psi(t)dw=\Psi(t)\varphi(t)$. That  is as far as I have gone.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem with random variables.  Suppose $X$ is your Laplace(0,1) rv, suppose $Y$ has distribution function $F$, suppose $Y$ is independent of $X$. Let $Z=Y+\epsilon X$.  The characteristic function of $Z$ is $E[e^{itZ}]=E[e^{itY}e^{it\epsilon X}]=E[e^{itY}]E[e^{it\epsilon X}]$ by independence.  Finally, tie these steps to the various functions $\Psi$, $\varphi$ and so on in your original statement.

This approach assumes you know the connection between convolution of distribution functions and addition of independent random variables; equivalently, the connection between the characteristic function of the convolution and those of the individual distributions.